# When I provision (sign) keys to end-users, can I force the definition of certificate expiration (different from CA expiration)?

Tags: ssh, csr

Before I proceed to testing this myself I wanted some clarity. I have a basic understanding of SSH and Cryptography but not completely sure about this plan. I want to implement a key rotation policy by enforcing that end user keys are only valid for 90 days, but I don't want to rotate my CA. Let's see this scenario (apologies if naive):

1. I have a CA for my startup
2. I sign keys for my end users (let's assume they generate the CSR)
3. I provide them a valid SSH Key
4. My CA Cert expires on 01/01/2030

From what I understand the expiration policy of the end user key is part of the CSR, so I can only reject the CSR but not change the key parameters like expiry. Is this assumption correct?

So I would have to instruct users to generate CSR with a limit following the rules, so then I could sign the request. But I can either sign or reject the request, but not provide the key with the expiration that I want to impose correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have some vocabulary questions. As you are speaking of CA and CSR, I would assume that you manage X509 certificates, where the key pairs are generated by the users, but you later say *I provide them a valid SSH Key*. Is is really a SSH Key or a X509 certificate?

Comment: That's my bad. I'm thinking of SSH only here. These keys would be to access systems over SSH (22).

Comment: Neat. I didn't even know that ssh _could_ use X.509 certificates.

Comment: I apologise If I'm asking an impossible question to start with. Can I simply just provide the key pair to the user without then sending me a CSR? And in that case I bet I could define the expiry on the individuals keys as I see fit.

Comment: The more I read here, the less I understand. AFAIK, the validity period should not even be present in a CSR. And anyway, the CA can set it in an X509 certificate. Said differently, the expiration policy is not part of the CSR but is under the control of the CA.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: _OpenSSH_ (only) has its own nonstandard kind of certificates; see https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.certkeys and https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#CERTIFICATES . bitoiu: If you do mean OpenSSH, that doesn't use any CSR; just get the plain-unsigned .pub file and apply ssh-keygen to create -cert.pub. You don't need and shouldn't get someone else's privatekey.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I understand my question is not the best in this area, I'm outside my area of expertise, but thank you for the help.